# Referencing a model class inside of a property in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

How do you reference a model class inside of a property validator?

My source code below. This is one of the properties from my model class `User`. The problem is in line 4, where keyword `self` is given. My goal is to pass the `User` model class to a validator (it will use it to search the class objects to validate that the login has unique value), but I don't know how to reference the class. `self` of course doesn't work.

```
class User(db.Model):
    (...)
    login = db.StringProperty(
        required=True,
        validator=combine_validators(
            validate_uniqueness_fun(self, "login", LoginNotAvailable),
            validate_string_fun(
                LOGIN_MIN_LENGTH,
                LOGIN_MAX_LENGTH,
                LOGIN_VALID_REGEX,
                LoginInvalidLength,
                LoginInvalidFormat
            )
        )
    )
    (...)
```

And the functions used in the property. `validate_string_fun()` is not that important, but similarly it returns validator functon that takes a property value as it's only argument.

```
def combine_validators(*validators):
    """
    Accepts any number of validators (validating functions) which it combines into
    one validator. The constructed function runs each given validator with that
    value.

    """  
    return functools.partial(
        _combine_validators,
        validators_list=[v for v in validators]
    )

def _combine_validators(value, validators_list):
    for validator in validators_list:
        validator(value)


def validate_uniqueness_fun(model, property_name, not_unique_exception):
    """
    Arguments:
    * model: subclass of google.appengine.ext.db.Model
    * property_name: string
    * property_not_unique: sub-clas of PropertyNotUnique

    Returns a function that given a value validates it's uniqueness. If in the
    property_name of the model class there already is a value equal to the
    given one, it raises property_not_unique exception.

    """
    return functools.partial(
        _validate_uniqueness,
        model=model,
        property_name=property_name,
        not_unique_exception=not_unique_exception
    )

def _validate_uniqueness(property_value, model, property_name, not_unique_exception):
    query = model.all().filter(property_name, property_value)
    if (query.get()):
        raise not_unique_exception(property_value)
```

Comment: What does `combine_validators` look like?

Comment: for starters you can't even use self in the this context, it doesn't exist yet.  You say in you question "My goal is to pass the User class object"  Do you really mean the instance of a User class ?  If so at the point of declaration you don't have it and it is meaningless.  Did you read the docs on validator " The function takes the value as its only argument, and raises an exception if the value is invalid. "  so the value of `login` will be passed into the validator (in your case whatever is returned from combine_validators), the entity holding the property won't be sent to the validator .

Comment: I really caution you to think carefully before taking this path. Think about it what happens when you retrieve the entity the second time and modify it (and not the login).  Unless you validation is smart enough to know that the object is being updated and not created, the validation will fire again and fail.

Comment: @MichaelJCox: I added `combine_validators()`.

Comment: @TimHoffman: I don't understand the point in your 2nd comment. Hope the  code of `combine_validators()` and `validate_uniqueness()` I've added will clear the case a bit.

Comment: Your validators will be run whenever you put() the entity to the datastore.  On create and update.  You can pass the model definition into your validators (ie use a string for the class name and register the models, then fetch the model definition at time of validation).  But the validator will only have the Model class and the value of the property no an instance of the model.  How can it tell the difference between and update and a create.  If you can't tell the difference then any time you update the entity (not the property) the validator will be run and will fail with a non unique error.

Comment: @TimHoffman: I get it now. I haven't thought it over well enough, forgot that validators are run also on an entity update. Looks like validating uniquneness in validator is a bad idea then. I'll do it somewhere else. Thank you for your explanation!

Comment: I would wrap the update of the entity in a higher level method that you always use to update properties which in then runs your validation before put.  Alternately use the login as part of the key.  If login needs to be editable create a separate entity for the login, that has a reference to the actual user.  Then you can construct a key and use get() to fetch a login, or get_or_insert safely to guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: I don't want to get into creating another tables and keys, because that's quite a lot of work. I have another property (email) that I aso want to be unique. I was trying to come up with a mechanism that would allow making any property unique easy implementable. Higher level method to update entities isn't a bad idea, but I have to think it over a little bit. Maybe I'll simply create class method `check_availability(property_name, property_value)` and manually invoke it each time I want to create/change property value.